# Does anyone knows how to import new classes when using Javascript instead of Groovy as default scripting language in SoapUI?

Tags: javascript, groovy, jar, import, soapui

I have a important piece of code that modifies my requests written Javascript, but i want to add an external jar and use it from the scripts, any suggestions? It's defined a sort of import function or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your own jars in Setup Script in SOAPUI with javascript language you must do the next steps:

With SOAPUI closed, copy your jars to SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext.

Start SOPAUI

On the project properties select Javascript for Script Language property.

Then in the Setup Script you have to reference the full package for your java classes like (I put a sample where I decode a base64 string):

```
    java.lang.System.out.println("-----------");
    java.lang.System.out.println("SAMPLE INIT");
    java.lang.System.out.println("-----------\n");
    var obj = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64();
    var stringb64 = new java.lang.String("dGVzdA==")
    var dataDecoded = obj.decodeBase64(stringb64.getBytes());
    java.lang.System.out.println("RESULT " + new java.lang.String(dataDecoded) + "\n");
    java.lang.System.out.println("-----------");
    java.lang.System.out.println("SAMPLE END");
    java.lang.System.out.println("-----------");
```

If you run soapui from .bat you can see the system out on the cmd:

[image: SOAPUI JS SAMPLE]

Comment: I did what you comment but i've found that only works with packages under java, com or org namespaces and looks like this are loaded by default. In my case I'm using a custom jar with a custom namespace system and when I try to do as you the interpreter reports that can't find the root of my namespace. This is happening just for JavaScript. In Groovy I can use my libaries just by importing it or using the fully qualified name as you in the example. I have solved my problem by using JsScriptEngine from groovy and runnig the JavaScript code.